# Javascript:: this.value is not working properly inside for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, this, settimeout, onmousedown

My code would pretty much speak for itself about what I'm about to achieve but just to clarify...

I want to return an the input value after long press (mousedown for 200ms).

It's working perfectly outside the for loop but inside the the loop it seems like not.

For `this.value` it returned undefined and for `gangina[i].value` it returned nothing.

Here is the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hezi_gangina/nxao19oc/

Here is my code :

```
<input type=button value=1>
<input type=button value=2>

<script>

var hezi;
var gangina=document.getElementsByTagName("input");

alert(gangina[1].value); //THIS IS OK! :)

for(i=0;i<gangina.length;i++)
{

    gangina[i].onmousedown=function()
    {
        hezi=setTimeout
        (
            function()
            {
                alert('this = '+this.value); // = undefined
                alert('gangina['+i+'] = '+gangina[i].value); // = nothing
            },200
        );
    }

}

</script>
```

Small tweak needed here...

Comment: Should you declare the i variable in your for loop like this? `for(var i=0; i<gangina.length; i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/nxao19oc/4/)**

You may need to wrap the function inside IIFE which will bind the `i` value.

Since the inner mousedown event handler will execute at some point, it will remember only the last value of `i`. Also note here that you've forgot to mention `var` infront of i as well.

If you want to assign the correct value of `i`, better wrap the inner function inside a IIFE function, now that event handler will refer to the locally scoped `i` at that moment. So it will always remember the correct value of `i`.

```
for(var i=0;i<gangina.length;i++)
{
   (function(i) {
    gangina[i].onmousedown=function()
    {
        var that = this;
        hezi=setTimeout
        (
            function()
            {
                alert('this = '+that.value); // = undefined
                alert('gangina['+i+'] = '+gangina[i].value); // = nothing
            },200
        );
    }
  })(i);

}
```

Also inside the `setTimeout`, `this` will refer to `Window` object not the DOM element.